# CKEditor add style on selection tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to add inline style directly into a selection text tag e.g.
I'm selecting`foo` within `<a>foo</a>` and click on the bold button.
Currently I have my config done so:

```
coreStyles_bold: {
  element: 'b',
  overrides: 'span',
  styles: { 'font-weight': 'bold' },
  childRule: function() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

which will convert my `<a>foo</a>` into

```
<a><span style="font-weight: bold;">foo</span></a>
```

I would like to achieve:

```
<a style="font-weight: bold;">foo</a>
```

Is this possible in CKEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be possible or not, it just does not make sense. Let's say a user was able to achieve this:

```
bar <a style="font-weight: bold;">foo</a> bar
```

Now, the user selects part of foo and part of bar and removes the bold...

```
bar <a style="font-weight: bold;">f[oo</a> ba]r
```

What would happen now?

```
bar <a style="font-weight: bold;">f</a><a>oo</a> bar
```

The end-user will think that there are two different links...